# Meteor: How to bind a paste event to html element?

Tags: javascript, events, meteor, paste

In Meteor, I'd like to bind a paste event to the `html` element, so that I can detect when the user tries to perform a paste--whether or not a field is in focus. In jQuery, I am able to achieve this with:

```
$('html').bind('paste', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("pasted");
});
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to duplicate this in Meteor. Here's what I tried:

```
Template.layout.events({
  'paste html' : function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert("pasted");
  }
}
```

I also tried using UI.body, but it was also unsuccessful:

```
UI.body.events({
  'paste': function () {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert("pasted");
  }
});
```

Comment: The `jQuery` code works out of the box with the latest Meteor, 0.7.1.2. I can paste anywhere in the standard Hello World app, and the event is caught. Is it an option to just use the jQuery code?

Comment: Oh hmm, let me give this a try. I had assumed I wouldn't be able to use any Meteor APIs if I used the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Posting @Dan Dascalescu's answer here so that this question can be closed.

jQuery code, especially in Meteor 0.8+, can be used out-of-the-box in Meteor.